# systemd-coredump files

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, mount, systemd-coredump

I was using a shared home partition (NTFS) between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.10 on my hp elitebook.  for about a good 3 months I had no issues, then today I went to copy a file while in Ubuntu in the shared partition and found that "root" had taken ownership.

I've shared a partition before without incident, and found that it's kind of a "no-no" to do.  So, I decided it was a good time to repartition anyway, and using a Ubuntu 20.10 Live USB I set out and used my HDD docking station to copy everything from the NTFS shared partition to a EXT4 partition, called "myfiles".  i did everything one folder/directory at a time (i only copied folders that'd be found in /home/user; nothing else).  I let every instance of each copy go without being stopped and without doing anything else on my laptop (no multitasking, no internet browsing, nothing, i just let it sit there and copy).

When everything was done, i restarted my laptop, everything turned on and mounted as it should - but when I went to the copied partition, "myfiles", i was told i didn't have permission to access or to see the partition because it was now "systemd-coredump."

1. i don't know what this means.
2. what did do that caused this? so i can avoid it again.
3. how do i fix this?

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu. a systemd-coredump file appears to indicate that your kernel dumped core, which mean it crashed at some point. It is very unclear what you are asking. Please issue the commands `fdisk -l` and `mount`; add the output to your question. Indicate which partition is the shared one.